# How to put the value of a variable inside a new LI element?

Tags: jquery

How do I put a variable name inside an li tag?

For exmaple,

```
var test_name = $('dt').text();

$('#test_div').html('<li> test_name </li>');
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong here. It displays test_name not the value of test_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a string containing your value:

```
$('#test_div').html('<li>' + test_name + '</li>');
```

Note that this is an XSS hole; you need to escape the HTML.
You can do that by building an element with jQuery:

```
$('#test_div').html(
    $('<li></li>').text(test_name)
);
```

Comment: Save yourself some keystrokes and use `<li>` in the construct. My carpal tunnel acts up when I see the qualified tag in a selector. ;p **edit** and now that you're dealing with a jQuery object, shouldn't you switch over to `.append()`?

Comment: @BradChristie: What? `append` won't clear the existing contents.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that shows a method that is valid for arbitrary input. However, it's a shame the ordering isn't reversed.

Comment: @Slaks: True, good call. I guess I see a `<li>` and just assume it's not going to be a singleton.

Comment: thanks all is working, and correct, I do need the append method